# Set meeting with Skype for business (lync) using rest api

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I successfully set a meeting using lync api (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/scheduleanonlinemeeting), but when the recepience of the meeting doesn't have the option to share their desktop.
I guess I need to add another param to the post request that I'm using.
Those are the current parameters:

```
                    HashMap<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
                    body.put("description", "");
                    body.put("subject", meeting.getSubject());
                    body.put("phoneUserAdmission", "Enabled");
                    body.put("accessLevel", "Everyone");
                    body.put("automaticLeaderAssignments", "Everyone");
                    body.put("lobbyBypassForPhoneUsers", "Enabled");
                    body.put("expirationTime", expirationDateString);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an permission issue. The administrator from Skype for Business (=SfB; former known as Lync) can control if it is possible to share an desktop. Additional the owner from the meeting can grant a 3rd party the rights to share his screen during a meeting session.

So you might start to check the rights here together with your Skype for Business Administrator...

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in body.put("automaticLeaderAssignment**s**", "Everyone")
its suppose to be body.put("automaticLeaderAssignment", "Everyone")
So now, every new recipient joining to the meeting has leader privileges, and is a presenter. I can't believe I spent 2 days on this!